# Pass IAM credential to netcore api deployed with aws lambda

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a Netcore api code that includes retrieving and uploading files to aws S3. It works when I run it locally since I have saved IAM credentials locally in another folder. However, when I deploy it with aws lambda function and try to access S3 I get AmazonS3Exception "access denied". I'm wondering how can I setup access to IAM credentials remotely as I have done locally?

Answer (score 0):

You should be [assigning an IAM role as the Lambda function's execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). Your code should be able to pick that up and use it automatically. If your code isn't picking that up automatically then edit your question to show the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Mark. Yes the lambda function has role with AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole policy. Am I required to add another policy to the role to access the IAM credential to use S3

Comment: Never mind, I just needed to  also add AmazonS3FullAccess permission to the role.